# function pointers and arbitrary parameters

Tags: c++

Imagine I want to write a function that does something with the values of two functions (like a comparison, as example).

f1 and f2 are examples, but it should work for more functions, independent of number and type of arguments.

```
double f1 (double x, double y, double z) {
    return pow(x,3)+2*pow(y,2)+3*z;
}

double f2 (std::vector<double> vec) {
    double result;
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){
        result += vec[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I want a compare function that I can call like this (or similar):

```
int main() {
    std::vector<double> example_vector {1,3,3,7};
    compare(f1, {4, 5, 6}, f2, example_vector);
    return 0
}
```

and inside compare it will call f1 with x=4, y=5, z=6 and f2 with vec=example_vector.

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution I used in the end:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

template<typename FuncA, typename FuncB, typename ...FA_Params, typename ...FB_Params>
void do_sth(FuncA &func_a, FuncB &func_b, const std::tuple<FA_Params ...> &a_params, const std::tuple<FB_Params ...> &b_params) {
    std::cout << std::apply(func_a, a_params) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::apply(func_b, b_params) << std::endl;
}

//f1, f2 and f3 are example functions

double f1 (double x, double y, double z) {
    return pow(x,3)+2*pow(y,2)+3*z;
}

double f2 (std::vector<double> vec) {
    double result;
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){
        result += vec[i];
    }
    return result;
}

double f3 (double a, double omega, double t, double delta) {
    double result;
    result = a*sin(omega*t+delta);
}

int main() {
    do_sth(f1, f2, std::make_tuple(1.0, 2.3, 1.3), std::make_tuple(std::vector<double>{1.0, 2, 3}));
    return 0;
}
```

C++20 doesn't work for me yet and this needs only C++17.

do_sth should be able to take any functions

Comment: it is not really clear what `compare` should compare. The results of the two function calls? That would be `<`. You didn't really ask a question btw

Comment: i dont understand what you want to do. You could write `compare( f1(4,5,6), f2(example_vector));` instead and actually just `f1(4,5,6) < f2(example_vector);`

Comment: Compare was just an example. In the actual program, I want to iterate over one of the variables like `x` and `vec[0]`, and compute for which value the relative difference between f1 and f2 is maximal. This would make the example a little bloated so I just made compare my example, knowing that it could have been solved easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the target here, so it's hard to make it a generic solution, but basically you can do something like that:

```
template<typename FuncA, typename FuncB>
void compare(FuncA func_a, const std::vector<double> &vec_a, FuncB func_b, const std::vector<double> &vec_b) {
    double res1 = func_a(vec_a[0], vec_a[1], vec_a[2]);
    double res2 = func_b(vec_b);
    // Do something...
}
```

There are probably more generic solutions to do what you want, but you'll have to clarify your target.

By the way, about `f2`:

```
double f2(std::vector<double> vec);
```

You can pass the vector by reference / const reference to avoid data copy:

```
double f2(const std::vector<double> &vec);
```

---

#### EDIT - Solve using variadic function

A little bit more generic approach could be:

```
template<typename FuncA, typename FuncB, typename FB_Param, typename ...FA_Params>
void compare(FuncA func_a, FuncB func_b, FB_Param b_param, FA_Params ...a_params) {
    func_a(a_params...);
    func_b(b_param);
}
```

The call may look something like this:

```
compare(f1, f2, std::vector<double>{1.0, 2, 3}, 1.0, 2.3, 1.3);
```

But the most important thing to notice, is that you can't combine two variadic params in the same function, so one of the functions you pass into this function should accept a single param (in this example, func_b).

---

#### EDIT - Solve using std::apply support

As [@fT3g0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11917733/ft3g0) idea to use tuples for multiple values, here is my version for c++20: Pass params as std::tuples/std::arrays/std::pair/anything that support std::apply implementation

```
template<typename Type>
concept ApplySupporter =
    requires (Type t) {
        { std::get<std::tuple_size<Type>() - 1>(t) };
        { std::tuple_size<Type>() };
    };

template<typename FuncA, ApplySupporter FA_Params, typename FuncB, ApplySupporter FB_Params>
void compare(FuncA func_a, FA_Params a_params, FuncB func_b, FB_Params b_params) {
    std::cout << std::apply(func_a, a_params) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::apply(func_b, b_params) << std::endl;
}
```

---

## Read About

[std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)
[concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)
[std::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)
[std::tuple_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size)

Comment: But now your function `compare` assumes of which types my functions are, because `res1 = func_a(vec_a[0], vec_a[1], vec_a[2]); ` doesn't work if func_a is f3, which depends, let's say on 4 arguments.


Yes you are right about the reference, thank you.

Comment: @fT3g0 The way you pass the param for f1 will never work, because `{4, 5, 6}` is a single param and not 3 params, so I assumed it'll always accept those params. You need to clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: @fT3g0 you can see my edit for a little bit more generic approach.

Comment: Thank you, this led me into the right direction and I found a post on how to use multiple parameter packs or wrap parameters into tuples. I will edit my original post with what I come up with when I end up putting my codepiece together.

Comment: @fT3g0 I liked your idea to use tuples (I actually thought of that but I forgot it called tuples lol), and I added an implementation for that. I highly recommend to try it first by yourself, and then check if you like my implementation.

Comment: I used your idea while taking out the stuff that requires C++20 and wrote my solution in the edit. Thanks again!